# Auto approve record when it is submitted for approval

Tags: apex, trigger, approval-process

I try to approve next step of approval process automatically, when submit for approval button is pressed. So, when the button is pressed, it updates two fields on record and then trigger is run. I try in different ways, but my code throws exception: `INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY` in line `Approval.ProcessResult[] appResult = Approval.process(prWkItems);`

What I am doing wrong?

My code is below (commented are not working):

```
trigger ITAssetTrigger on IT_Asset__c (after update) {

    for(IT_Asset__c it: Trigger.new){   

        Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest[] prWkItems = New Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest[]{};
        ProcessInstance[] pi = [Select ID, Status, TargetObject.Name, (SELECT Id, ActorId, ProcessInstanceId FROM Workitems), (SELECT Id, StepStatus, Comments FROM Steps) From ProcessInstance Where TargetObjectID = :it.Id AND Status = 'Pending'];    

        for(ProcessInstance instance : pi){      
            for(ProcessInstanceWorkItem workItem : instance.WorkItems){                
                Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest prWkItem = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();

                prWkItem.setWorkItemID(workItem.id);
                prWkItem.setComments('Request Canceled by User: ' + userInfo.getName());
                prWkItem.setAction('Approve');
                prWkItems.add(prWkItem);                
            }
        }

        if(!prWkItems.isEmpty()){
            //shouldTriggerRun.stopFAR();
            Approval.ProcessResult[] appResult = Approval.process(prWkItems);
            //shouldTriggerRun.allowFAR();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Clean up the code and post relevant code which is related to the issues

Comment: @SantanuBoral, cleared